# Output additional attributes WEKA 3.8

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka

I am using GUI version of WEKA and I am classifying using the Random Forest. I'm trying to find out which instances are misclassified.

I know that earlier versions of WEKA had and option of "Output additional attributes" where I can add instance Id and get around this problem, but now with WEKA 3.8 I can't see this option.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, on the preprocess tab you need to use the filter addID or you can add your own attribute as string. Then you would have to use the classifier "FilteredClassifier" click on it and use the filter "Remove" specifying the index of the attribute that holds the id, and then start the classification.

To see the misclassified, right click on the the result int he Result List, choose Visualize classifier errors, then choose save as arff. This will result in seeing all the instances with their prediction.